# Login screen problems

Tags: boot, 14.04

I downloaded Ubuntu onto my HP computer tonight and I am unable to login. When I restart my computer, it shows me a black screen and asks for my login name and password which I provide. It then says something like kelly@kellybrown and wants me to type something, but no matter what I type it doesn't let me go past the screen. What can I do or how do I get past this screen. Did I do something wrong during the download?

Comment: It would be interesting to see if you can get to your normal desktop environment by entering the command `sudo service lightdm start` which will bring up your normal graphical login screen and then you can log in to your desktop from there. After that you could use the built-in Additional Drivers utility to check if your computer is missing a proprietary graphics display driver.

Comment: that does not work either.

Comment: Please login with your username and password from the black screen and then provide the results of running the command: `lspci -nn | grep VGA` which will tell whether you are missing a display graphics driver, which can also be installed from the same screen.

Comment: after I type that in it says 00:12.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation C67 [GeForce 7150M / nForce 6 30MJ [10de:0531] (rev a2)

Comment: Please login with your username and password from the black screen. Your Nvidia GeForce 7150M is an older GPU, so I recommend that instead of the current proprietary Nvidia graphics driver you instead the next older one. Enter this command: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-173`. Then to enable the graphics driver that you installed reboot by running this command: `sudo shutdown -r now`. Please comment about the results because you may still need to do one more step.

Comment: Didn't work what else should I do?

Comment: It restarted but went to same screen

Comment: From the same black screen login and remove the graphics driver that didn't work: `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-173`. Now I don't know what other Nvidia driver to tell you to try. The other available Nvidia drivers are (in ascending order from older to newer) as follows: nvidia-current, nvidia-310, nvidia-319, and nvidia-331 which can be installed the same way you installed nvidia-173.

Comment: Is there any way I can uninstall and start over?

Comment: You don't need to uninstall Ubuntu to start over. The Ubuntu installer will show you a graphical **Allocate Drive Space** screen with an option to replace your old Ubuntu OS which doesn't work with the new Ubuntu OS that you are installing. I have been searching to find the correct driver for your GPU, and it seems that the nvidia-173 graphics driver is the right driver for your GPU.

Comment: You installed Ubuntu server instead of Ubuntu desktop. Most people use Ubuntu server headless without any desktop environment, so that would explain why you can't login to the Ubuntu desktop environment.

Comment: So now what do I do?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to download the Ubuntu desktop onto any Windows PC that you have available and then follow the instructions from ubuntu.com at [How to create a bootable USB
stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). You will need to use a USB flash drive that has at least 2GB.

Comment: So I retried the 173 and it asked if wanted to update new software, said yes. It then says E:unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix missing? What should I do?

Comment: Search the Dash for *Software Sources*, click the Software & Updates icon to open the Software & Updates window, then under the *Ubuntu Software* tab make sure there is a check mark in the first four checkboxes in the list under the **Downloadable from the internet** heading. Then open the terminal using the keyboard combination Ctrl+Alt+T and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to install all of the updates for your new Ubuntu installation. It might take a half hour or more to install all of the updates for your new Ubuntu installation. Then retry to install nvidia-173.

Comment: Where am I suppose to do the first part at??

Comment: The Dash is the top icon in the row of icons on the left hand side of the desktop. The Dash icon is a white circular form with a purple background. The Dash is the place where you can search for the icons for all the other applications that do not already appear on the vertical row of icons on the desktop (called the Launcher in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you don't have the GUI installed in your version of Ubuntu. To solve this, type the following commands after you login to Ubuntu and get this - kelly@kellybrown

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

You need a working internet connection for this.

OR

You might have to reinstall Ubuntu.

By the way, have you downloaded the correct iso? You can download the desktop version of Ubuntu from [this page on the official site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Comment: what if I downloaded the wrong one? how do I change it to the correct one if I cannot get into my computer?

Comment: Can you boot to your Ubuntu using the "Try Ubuntu" option?

Comment: the above process did not work what is the next step to do?

Comment: try Ubuntu did not work either

Comment: What error are you getting in try ubuntu

Comment: should I try to re down load the disc?

Comment: says command not available

Comment: I meant that you already have a disk of ubuntu with you na, boot from it and select "Try Ubuntu".

Comment: When I put disc in I do not have that option

Comment: Then you might have to download the correct iso file from the above mentioned link. Sorry but please bear with it. And thank you for your patience.

Comment: How do I do that when I cannot log into my. Computer

Comment: What are the options you are getting on boot?

Comment: Install, multiple server install with MAAS, check disc for defects(which I did), test memory, boot from first hard disk, rescue broken system

Comment: As you have downloaded the server edition of Ubuntu, you can browse the web but it includes a lot of commands. Can't you download Ubuntu Desktop from somewhere else?

Comment: I only have tablet which does not have cd drive

Comment: You can atleast download the desktop iso to your tab.

Comment: so if I download it to my tab will I be able to save it to my USB drive?

Comment: Yes, you can save it to a USB or rather burn it to a USB or DVD from another computer with a working OS.